# Not an association in nHibernate criteria (Asp.Net MVC4)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate

I am using the following code to fetch data from table tMenu. But it returning an error 
"Not an Association : MenuID"

```
 public virtual IList<FOSEntities.Menu> GetMenuByRole(string RoleID)
    {
        try
        {
            ICriteria criteria = nHibernateHelper.OpenSession().CreateCriteria(typeof(FOSEntities.MenuSecurity), "MenuSecurity");
            criteria.CreateAlias("MenuSecurity.MenuID", "Menu", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
            criteria.CreateAlias("MenuSecurity.RoleID", "Roles", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
            criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Roles.RolesID", RoleID));

            criteria.SetProjection(new IProjection[] { Projections.ProjectionList()
            .Add(Projections.Property("Menu.MenuID"), "MenuID")                
            .Add(Projections.Property("Menu.MenuName"), "MenuName")
             });                
            IList<Menu> menu = criteria.List<FOSEntities.Menu>();
            return menu;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

please help me out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `criteria.CreateAlias("MenuSecurity.MenuID", ...)` seems to be *(due to common naming conventions)* joining the `int` property `MenuID`. And that's not the way how relations/associations are working from the NHibernate perspsective.

We need to have C# entity properties

```
public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
// instead of
// public virtual int MenuID { get; set; }
// public virtual int RoleID { get; set; }
```

And then join them like this:

```
criteria.CreateAlias("MenuSecurity.Menu", "Menu" , NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
criteria.CreateAlias("MenuSecurity.Role", "Roles", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
```

See [15.4. Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-associations) for more details

Comment: Kohler, I had pop up attributes in the corresponding classes. and i changed the criteria as like follows  and now getting an error "The value "System.Object[]" is not of type "FOSEntities.Menu" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
Parameter name: value"

Comment: I see. This is related to the fact, that we've used the Projections. So, the resulat is not `MenuSecurity` any more, it is different object. So, what we recieve is an array of `object[]`. I mean, this should be the result: `var menu = criteria.List<object[]>();` OR, we can use the result transformers **Please** check the link in my answer and search for `SetResultTransformer` (or even google) ... the transformation is different topic ... ;)